# Infer class of has_many relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a `User` class with the following `has_many` relation:

```
class User
  has_many :created_things, :class_name => 'Thing'
end
```

Given an instance of `User`, call it `u`, how can I programmatically determine the class of the elements of `u.created_things`? I would like to do this even if `u.created_things` is empty (in which case `u.created_things.class` just returns `Array`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Arel to determine the class of the association.  The below will result in the string "Thing".

```
u.created_things.arel_table.engine.to_s
```

Comment: But in the case where `u.created_things == []`, that will be `NilClass`

Comment: For the second case, correct.  So, you always want to return "Thing"?

Comment: How about using the arel_table: u.created_things.arel_table.engine.to_s

Comment: that is it! If you edit that into your answer, I'll check it as the answer to my question.